# How to calculate compound interest monthly

Tags: c#, math

I want a calculate compound interest monthly based. I get some examples but they provide based on yearly.

For example :-

I have Principal,Rate and Time (months)
Let's suppose

```
double Principal=1000;
double Rate=0.03;
double Time=12 months
double Amount=?
```

What should be the formula to get compound interest based on months not year

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math formula not programming

Comment: is the interest rate 3% per month or per year? Take out a pen and paper and think about how you would do the calculations.

Comment: @user1666620 Its per month

Answer (score 2):

**You should provide mathematical formula, here we are working on programming problems.**

After research in the web, I found this [article](http://www.financeformulas.net/Compound_Interest.html)

```
C=P*((1+r)^n - 1)
```

If the formula is correct you need some code like this:

```
double principal=1000;
double rate=0.03;
double time=12;
double Amount= principal*(Math.Pow(1+rate, time) -1);
```

Here hope this helps, if not please add the correct formula !

Comment: its not working its returning same as principal 1000

Comment: @Andrew the op question is not really clear. From the article if the rate is per year, he should divide the rate by 12. Because he want to calculated monthly interest. Probably I'm mistaken, I'm not good in finance :)

Comment: @mukesh if the rate is per year, you should divide rate/12 in Math.Pow ! Read the article which I post, I'm not here for finical advices !

Comment: I special mentioned I need monthly compound interest not yearly...:)

Comment: @mukesh you mention but you never tell us, what are the variables per year or per month ! Which obviously is crucial. Check the formula after my update ! *double Amount= principal*(Math.Pow(1+rate/12, time) -1);* This is what you need

Comment: I think you need the yearly compound interest. The monthly interest is what you already have.

Comment: Rate shouldn't be divided by 12. If the rate was yearly, you should do `Math.Pow(1 + rate, 1 / time) - 1`, as I first thought (you can find that in my original answer).

Comment: @mybirthname I am also not too strong in finicial..But I need to get the result's based on monthly..

Answer (score 0):

After you clarified that the rate is monthly, you have to find the 12th power of your rate + 1:

```
double yearlyRate = Math.Pow(Rate + 1, 12) - 1;
```

In your case, it's 0.425760886846 (42.576%).

So `1000 * yearlyRate` = 425.76 in interests.

Comment: not working giving same values as principal 1000

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, probably some rounding issue due to using `int` literals.

Comment: Could you solve this?

Comment: I no more need of this formula...I did some custom ways instead of using math methods